# Guard Rspec :cli option is deprecated, change to :cmd option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard

Working `Guardfile`in my rails app

`guard 'rspec', all_after_pass: false, cli: '--drb' do`

Not working `Guardfile`

`guard 'rspec', all_after_pass: false, cmd: '--drb' do`

I've opened guard with `bundle exec guard` many times, but I found even though I receive this message
`Guard::RSpec DEPRECATION WARNING: The :cli option is deprecated. Please customize the new :cmd option to fit your need.`
and I make the proper changes, :cli is the only one working with rspec.

terminal output for `:cli`

```
01:49:14 - WARN - Guard::RSpec DEPRECATION WARNING: The :cli option is deprecated. Please customize the new :cmd option to fit your need.
01:49:15 - INFO - Guard is using Growl to send notifications.
01:49:15 - INFO - Guard is using Emacs to send notifications.
01:49:15 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
01:49:15 - INFO - Starting Spork for RSpec
Using RSpec, Rails
Preloading Rails environment
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
01:49:17 - INFO - Spork server for RSpec successfully started

01:49:17 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
01:49:17 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/Users/me/rails_projects/mvp'
[1] guard(main)> 
01:49:18 - INFO - Run all
01:49:18 - INFO - Running all specs
Running tests with args ["--color", "--failure-exit-code", "2", "--format", "progress", "--format", "Guard::RSpec::Formatter", "--require", "/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails40/gems/guard-rspec-4.2.4/lib/guard/rspec/formatter.rb", "spec"]...
......................................................................

Finished in 0.76464 seconds
70 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 47137

Done.
```

terminal output for `:cmd`

```
bundle exec guard
01:58:55 - INFO - Guard is using Growl to send notifications.
01:58:55 - INFO - Guard is using Emacs to send notifications.
01:58:55 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
01:58:55 - INFO - Starting Spork for RSpec
Using RSpec, Rails
Preloading Rails environment
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
01:58:57 - INFO - Spork server for RSpec successfully started

01:58:57 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
01:58:57 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/Users/me/rails_projects/mvp'
[1] guard(main)> 
01:58:59 - INFO - Run all
01:58:59 - INFO - Running all specs

[2] guard(main)>
```

Just leave the `:cli` or is there a solution?

Comment: You didn't customize it to fit your needs - you just copied the `cli` to `cmd` and expected it to work

Comment: Ah I see what I did wrong. I'll post answer

Comment: I can't post answer, so here.

`:cmd` needs to execute something that is customized to fit my needs. As @sevenseacat said, "You didn't customize it to fit your needs - you just copied the cli to cmd and expected it to work"

I'm running Spork, Guard, and Rspec for testing. Instead of just writing `--drb` I should prepend it with `rspec`

Fixed `Guardfile` has

`guard 'rspec', all_after_pass: false, cmd: 'rspec --drb' do`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

:cmd needs to execute something that is customized to fit my needs. As @sevenseacat said, "You didn't customize it to fit your needs - you just copied the cli to cmd and expected it to work"

I'm running Spork, Guard, and Rspec for testing. Instead of just writing --drb I should prepend it with `rspec`

Fixed Guardfile has

`guard 'rspec', all_after_pass: false, cmd: 'rspec --drb' do`